# Layout not taking properties from merge tag

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, custom-view

I have next layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_round_rect_4_melanzane_dark"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
        <EditText />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am inflating it in custom view like:

```
class LabeledEditText : RelativeLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.view_labeled_edit_text, this)
    }
}
```

Everything works fine. But if I change RelativeLayout to merge tag in my xml, my view not getting properties such background and focusable. This is how I am changing it:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_round_rect_4_melanzane_dark"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    tools:parentTag="android.widget.RelativeLayout">
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
        <EditText />
</merge>
```

What I must do for getting params from merge tag to parent layout in my custom view?

Comment: Did you change `RelativeLayout` to `merge` in your custom view? Change `class LabeledEditText : RelativeLayout` to `class LabeledEditText : merge`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout won't take properties from merge tag.